# What other programs can open Adobe Audtition .sesx files?

Tags: adobe-audition, format, file, compatibility, session

`.sesx` files are Adobe Audition editing session files and contain non-destructive edit decision lists (EDL) of separate audio files (e.g. `.wav`) that they reference, the `.sesx` file also including multi-track information for playback fo multiple audio tracks using these files.

Other Adobe file formats - `.ai` and `.psd` from Illustrator and Photoshop respectively, can be edited by many other programs.

Similarly, I'd like to find out what other apps can open `.sesx` files as it gives users more options, particularly given that the latest Audition is a subscription app.  The user may want to know they can access their editing work in the future, but do so infrequently and therefore a subscription arrangement may not be suitable.

**Related information about my own setup that may be useful to others and for context**

Myself, I have a genuine Adobe CS6 Production license, which includes Audition. CS6 is the last version of such Adobe suite of apps before the subscription based CC was introduced. Adobe Audition CS6 can generate, open and save `.sesx` files - full support of this format in this version of Audition onwards. Indeed, I think Audition CS5/CS5.5/CS6 is where the `.sesx` format was introduced and therefore Audition is the original official app for it.

I also have genuine licenses of earlier versions of Adobe Audition, again non-subscription:

- version 3.0 - which can save `.xml` files but I'm not sure if these are the same XML schema/format as `.sesx`.
- version 1.5 - which saves edit sessions as a binary ses format. I have a version of [ses2sesx](https://www.aatranslator.com.au/ses2sesx.html) which can generate `.sesx` files from their `.ses` equivalents.

Being an XML file which can be examined by inspection and perhaps a little more easily reverse engineer-able, I would guess it could be possible for the development of a program to read this or as a plug-in extension e.g. for open source Audacity.  On that note, is reverse-engineering how being able to open `.ai` and `.psd` files by non-Adobe programs came about, or did Adobe publish a specification somewhere for others to use?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question at the same time as asking. So far I have found one editor program that apparently can open Adobe Audition `.sesx` files:

It's a feature among one of the [editions of Hindenburg Journalist](https://hindenburg.com/products) - I'm not sure yet whether it's in the non-PRO or the more expensive PRO.  At least this program is available as a non-subscription option.   The reference to `.sesx` support is mentioned at [on this release notes page at Version 1.81 Build 2276](https://hindenburg.com/support/release-notes) Though I'm not sure if it's full import edit and export.